# Quotient set of an "equivalence relation" without reflexivity

Tags: relations, quotient-set

Let $\sim$ be some symmetric and transitive relation on a set $X$. Couldn't the notion of a quotient set still be defined, where some elements may "vanish"?

For example, let $A=\{1,2,...,7\}$, and let $1\sim2\sim3$ and $5\sim6\sim7$. Could I define $A/\sim$ as $\{[1],[5]\}$, where the $4$ "vanishes"?

My thinking is that the only "purpose" of reflexivity is to guarantee the existence of an equivalence class for every element. If my idea has some merit, then is there a name for this kind of relation?

Comment: The purpose of reflexivity is that it's one of the conditions a *notion of equivalence* should satisfy; the reason they're called equivalence relations is that they are relations describing ways in which things can be equivalent. If your notion of equivalence has the property that a thing isn't equivalent to itself that's a strange thing to be calling an equivalence. If you want to remove some elements just do that before bringing a relation into it.

Comment: I see. For the construction I want, I may just as well create a sequence $A\to E\to E/\sim$, where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $E\subset A$.

Comment: Oh, but this seems to induce some sort of "monoidal" structure, where given some equivalence relation $\sim$, we have a group of maps $A\to A$ that preserve the equivalence classes, where for my $\sim$, the maps that preserve the "equivalence" classes are not necessarily invertible, although this might be an obvious observation categorically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [partial equivalence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_equivalence_relation) (PERs). They come up frequently in the semantics of programming languages and related topics. The quotient-like operation you mention is also used, and works the way that you expect.

For instance, the PERs on [Kleene's first algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+combinatory+algebra#examples_of_pcas) make up a notable subcategory of the [effective topos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_topos), equivalent to the associated category of modest sets. These are the sets that are able to be represented by values in the algebra, such that each element of the algebra represents at most one element of the set (so, the sets cannot be bigger than the set of values in the algebra). The PER determines which values in the algebra represent equivalent elements, and which do not represent any element at all (the ones for which reflexivity fails). The quotient-like operation gives you (something isomorphic to) the represented set.